# Catch console.log but keep information of caller in browser's console

Tags: javascript

Can I catch console.log calls but still show the correct caller information / link to source code in the browser's console?

I know I can do

**myModule.js**

```
  var oldLog = console.log;
  console.log = function (message) {
    // ... I want to do something here in this line ...  
    oldLog.apply(console, arguments);
  }
```

But when I do this, then the browser's console will **always** show `myModule.js` as the source of the log message. Not the module that actually called the (overwritten) `console.log()` method.

Comment: Well that is where you write it so that is going to happen.

Comment: I don't think you can use the browser's automatic log-source to do this, but you can still find out where the call came from. Is that acceptable? Will you have to account for IE?

Comment: [`console.trace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/trace) displays a full stack trace — try that.

Comment: You might be able to combine Sebastian's suggestion with this post from Remy Sharp: https://remysharp.com/2014/05/23/where-is-that-console-log